# How do I pass "ACPI=OFF" to my kernel on boot?

Tags: boot, kernel

When I tried to upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10 the system froze, so I've been playing around with a couple other linux builds (Fedora, Mint, and Puppy) the last couple days and I keep coming around to the same problem: a lockup during boot; each build referencing a kernel error.  On another board someone suggested booting with a boot up line of "ACPI = off".

It works with other OS', but I'm not sure where to put this command.  Can anyone 'enlighten' me, please?

Answer (score 1):

In `/etc/default/grub`

The last line you have to change.

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0 GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0 GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10 GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null ||
echo Debian` GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi=off"
```

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions